# wrong LLDB behavior (C struct sizeof) on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

I've compiled the following C code as part of vary basic iOS application:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long long l1;
    int l2;
} AAA;
int l;
l = sizeof(AAA);
```

When running this code on the iPhone 3 device (upgraded to the latest iOS 5.1) the LLDB (XCode 4.3.2) debugger tells the value of variable `l` is 12, but `sizeof(AAA)` is 16.

```
(lldb) p l
(int) $0 = 12
(lldb) p sizeof(AAA)
(unsigned int) $1 = 16
```

Running the same code on iPhone simulator behaves OK (both `l` and `sizeof(AAA)` are 12)

Is it something known? Do I miss something?

Comment: Did not try. Actually I don't know how to configure the debugger to be GDB.

Comment: Oh, it is in your "Edit Schemes" section

Comment: Thanks.GDB is OK (both are 12)

Comment: Then chalk it up to LLDB being weird I guess.  It's done really weird things to me before in the past too.